# Azure Application Gateway with dynamic private IP: how can I know its current IP?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I've created an Azure Application Gateway with the following frontend configurations:

```
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
            {
                "name": "...",
                "id": "....",
                "etag": "...",
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations",
                "properties": {
                    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                    "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                    "publicIPAddress": {
                        "id": "..."
                    },
                    "httpListeners": [
                        {
                            "id": "..."
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "..."
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "..."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

So this Application Gateway has 1 public IP address, and 1 private IP address with `privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"`. However, I cannot find any API call, or place in the UI, where I can determine the runtime private IP address of the Application Gateway. Is there a way to know, or is it not relevant?

**Use-case:** I need, at runtime, to determine if an IP I see (I only have IP and port) is that of an Application Gateway, whether it's the Gateway's private IP, or public IP. I can easily see what's the public IP by going to the Public IPs section in the Azure UI, but **how can I know what is the current value of a dynamically allocated private IP?**

Comment: Did you tried using [GET Aplication Gateway REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/application-gateways/get?tabs=HTTP) ? In the response you get `frontendIPConfigurations` property which has both public and private IPs along with their allocation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure Application Gateway with 1 public an 1 private Ip address with `privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"` like below:

[image]

As suggested by *Abhinandan Bharamgunde* I have tried using RestAPI

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}?api-version=2022-09-01
```

To get an Application Gateways using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/application-gateways/get?tabs=HTTP) when I run the request by selecting try it I got successfully result like below:

[image]

[image]

```json
"name": "appGwPrivateFrontendIpIPv4",
        "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b8xxxxxx/resourceGroups/v-imrankXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/imranappgateway/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPrivateFrontendIpIPv4",
        "etag": "W/\"96528c0d-fb7c-453d-b596-566a9XXXX\"",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations",
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.6",
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "subnet": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5XXXXX/resourceGroups/20230308173XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/appvnet/subnets/default"
          },
          "httpListeners": [
```

> **how can I know what is the current value of a dynamically allocated private IP?**

To check the value of allocated private Ip using CLI:

```
az network application-gateway show --name <gateway-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --query 'frontendIPConfigurations[].privateIPAddress'
```

[image]

In powershell:

```
(Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <gateway-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>).FrontendIPConfigurations.PrivateIPAddress
```

[image]

In App gateway click on listener change frontend end as private like below:

[image]

you can able to see public and private address of allocated in  Frontend IP configurations like below:

[image]